# What's the difference with or without backtick "`"?

Tags: ocaml

```
type level =
[ `Debug
| `Info
| `Warning
| `Error]
```

Can i remove the "`" here ?

Sincerely!

Comment: This is related (somewhat) to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746743/extending-an-existing-type-in-ocaml/1747400#1747400

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's hard to answer this question yes or no.

You can remove the backticks and the square brackets.  Then you would have

```
type level2 = Debug | Info | Warning | Error
```

In the simplest cases, this type is is very similar to your type `level`.  It has 4 constant constructors.

In more complex cases, though, the types are quite different.  Your type `level` is a [polymorphic variant](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/polyvariant.html) type, which is more flexible than `level2` above.  The constructors of `level` can appear in any number of different types in the same scope, and `level` participates in subtyping relations:

```
# type level = [`Debug | `Info | `Warning | `Error]
# type levelx = [`Debug | `Info | `Warning | `Error | `Fatal]

# let isfatal (l: levelx) = l = `Fatal;;
val isfatal : levelx -> bool = <fun>
# let (x : level) = `Info;;
val x : level = `Info
# isfatal (x :> levelx);;
- : bool = false
```

The point of this example is that even though x has type `level`, it can be treated as though it were of type `levelx` also, because `level` is a subtype of `levelx`.

There are no subtyping relations between non-polymorphic variant types like `level2`, and in fact you can't use the same constructor name in more than one such type in the same scope.

Polymorphic variant types can also be open-ended.  It's a big topic; if you're interested you should see section 4.2 of the OCaml manual, linked above.

Comment: afair, the preferrable name now is "open variants".

Comment: I thought open variants referred to things like exceptions? also does levelx need to be a subset or superset of level here? Can it just be an intersection? Can it mix backtick variants and non-backtick variants?

Comment: Is [4.2 Labels and type interference](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/lablexamples.html#s:label-inference) really the section you mean?