# Don't understand symbols in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocaml-batteries

I'm learning OCaml these days by some basic material and a project written in OCaml. But I don't understand some symbols in OCaml. For example:

```
open Batteries

type char_token = [ 
      | `Char of int
      | `Escape of char list
      ]
```

what's these things with symbol ` mean? 
And also other symbols are hard for me to understand:

- **|>**
- **_**

I can't find anything in the [OCaml Manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/index.html). Can somebody explain more details about the symbols above? Or just recommend some material to me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`` `Foo `` and `[>` are polymorphic variants (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual006.html#toc36). They are probably not worth it for a beginner, but you could look at one of my old answers ([Extending an existing type in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746743/extending-an-existing-type-in-ocaml/1747400#1747400)) to see how to use them.

`_` is a pattern that matches anything:

```
let head l = match l with
| x :: _ -> x
| _ -> failwith "empty list"
```

Both `_` there are used to say to the compiler "something I don't care about".

Comment: The tilde is not an operator on it's own; there is `~-` and `~-.` which define unary negation for integers and floating point numbers, respectively. These are all listed in the `Pervasives` module documentation.

Comment: There is another use for ~. In OCaml, you can define functions labelled (i.e. named) arguments, as in: `let f ~x ~y = x - y`. Now, you can pass arguments to `f` based on the names and not on the position: `let x = 2 in let y = 1 in f ~y ~x` will return `1` and not `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers that begin with a ` are [polymorphic variants](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lablexamples.html#sec46). They are structurally typed variants, roughly speaking.

`|>` is an infix operator: you are probably thinking of the one defined in [Batteries](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc/BatStd.html), which is function application (`x |> f` meaning `f x`).

`_` is a special symbol in match patterns meaning "match anything without making a binding".

Comment: `|>` was actually added to the standard library in 4.01.